# Excel VBA Macro: incorporating filters and using a macro to delete visible and subsequent empty rows

Tags: excel, filter, delete-row, worksheet-function, vba

I have a spreadsheet with ~50,000 rows of data. This value will fluctuate because I have a function to bring in more data.

What I am hoping to do is be able to use my column filters (Row 2) to display the items I do not want. **Then the macro** will delete all the visible values, turn off the filters, delete all the empty rows, and finally turn the filters in row 2 back on. The following code is designed to do this but leaves empty rows throughout the data matrix. Thank you for your help!

```
Sub DeleteVisible_Empty_BlankRows()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Range("C3:V" & rows.count).ClearContents
  Worksheets("MyDataPull").AutoFilterMode = False

'Ungroup & regroup necessary columns
  Columns("F:K").Columns.Ungroup

  Dim r As Range, emrows As Long, i As Long
  LRI = Mydatapull.Cells(Mydatapull.rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

'Filter column C from A to Z so that blanks are put at the bottom
  Range("C3:V" & LRI).Sort Key1:=Range("C3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

'Filter to only show blanks
  Range("C3:V" & LRI).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=" & ""

'Delete blanks
  Range("C3:V" & LRI).EntireRow.Delete

'Turn filters back on
  Worksheets("MyDataPull").AutoFilterMode = False

'Delete Extra rows
  LRI = Mydatapull.Cells(Mydatapull.rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
  Range("C" & LRI + 1 & ":V" & rows.count).EntireRow.Delete

  Mydatapull.Range("C2:V2").AutoFilter
  Columns("F:K").Columns.Group

End Sub
```

Comment: Just sort it after the deletes to put all the blanks at the bottom

Comment: I tried using `Range("C3:C" & LRI).Sort Key1:=Range("C3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal` but this just puts the blank rows at the bottom. I want to actually delete the rows

Comment: How can you distinguish between a blank row and a deleted row? If the blank rows are at the bottom won't it look the same if they were deleted?

Comment: The blank rows still show up as "blanks" in the filter menu options and take up significant row space when opening and closing the file. i.e. I have 100 rows of actual data but my sheet is saving 1000 rows of blank rows (this is seen also by the scroll bar on the right being very small even though the non-blank rows are relatively few)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. See the updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried first unfiltering the data, then deleting the empty rows? I've personally had more success working with content when sheets are unfiltered.
Try adding:

`ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
 ActiveSheet.ShowAllData`

before you delete the empty rows.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: That already exists in the code I post above... ^^^ 
`Worksheets("MyDataPull").AutoFilterMode = False`

Comment: Good point, didn't see that. If you're trying to delete the entire row, make sure you include `.EntireRow`. Otherwise, I saw that your variable `Mydatapull` hasn't been defined, but I assume that is just shorthand for `Worksheets("MyDataPull")`. What value are you getting for `LRI`?

Comment: I updated the code I am using. LRI is the last row in the index. `mydatapull` is the literal name of the sheet so it works just like `worksheets("mydatapull")` My issue is that this code works but it leaves the blanks at the bottom meaning that I still see the blanks in the filter menu (in row 2) and the scroll bar is super small making the sheet load slowly